# cannot resolve method pointerSize(POINTER_SIZE)

Tags: android, tooltip

I have created tool tip to android application, this working fine, but try to add pointer size throws this exception , below my code

```
new SimpleTooltip.Builder(getActivity())
.anchorView(downArrow_image)
.gravity(Gravity.TOP)
.pointerSize(15)
//.transparentOverlay(false)
.text(finalInvestigationValue[0])
.animated(true)
.build().show();
```

Comment: Can you post LogCat error log of exception?

Comment: there is no class like `SimpleTooltip` in Android. Are you using some lib?

Comment: yes, i am using lib, compile 'com.github.douglasjunior:android-simple-tooltip:0.1.2'